# Threadpool en Ruby: error de módulo no definido al usar pool.schedule

Tags: ruby, hilos, schedule

```
#!/bin/env ruby
require 'threadpool'
def time_taken
  now = Time.now.to_f
  yield
  Time.now.to_f - now
end

def test_time_taken
  pool_size = 5
  pool = ThreadPool.new(pool_size)
  elapsed = time_taken do
    pool_size.times do
      pool.schedule { sleep 1 }
    end
    pool.shutdown
  end
  assert_operator 4.5, :>, elapsed,
    'Elapsed time was too long: %.1f seconds' % elapsed
end
test_time_taken
```

Este es el error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 19: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
> 18: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `load'
> 17: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.3.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
> (irb):15:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `wxit' for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Se me hace que no pusiste todo tu código, pero supongo en alguna parte pusiste `wxit` en vez de `exit`

Comment: tranquilo, ya lo resolví, hubo actualizaciones en la gema threadpool y ya el módulo schedule no existe, cambio de nombre a process, y si, el código esta completo

Comment: Amigo, tienes idea de cómo hacer fuerza bruta con threadpool? Es para terminar el trabajo más rápido #Ruby